# How to tell Buildout to install a egg from a URL (w/o pypi)

Tags: python, buildout, egg

I have some egg accessible as a URL, say http://myhosting.com/somepkg.egg .
Now I don't have this somepkg listed on pypi. How do I tell buildout to fetch and install it for me. 
I have tried a few recipes but no luck so far.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to add a 'find-links' option to your [buildout] section within the buildout.cfg file. I just tested this internally with the following buildout.cfg.

```
[buildout]
find-links  = http://buildslave01/eggs/hostapi.core-1.0_r102-py2.4.egg
parts = mypython

[mypython]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = mypython
eggs = hostapi.core
```

You can just specify the full path to the egg as the value to 'find-links.' Make sure the egg's 'pyx.y' version matches your local Python version. If they don't match, you'll get a not found error which is slightly misleading.

Comment: You can also specify the directory where eggs/sdists are stored.

Comment: and if the egg also exist on pypi, you can overwrite the index ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852842/how-do-i-tell-buildout-to-ignore-a-binary-distribution-and-build-from-source-ins/18915179#18915179