# Buildout ignoring github `find-links` reference

Tags: python, github, buildout

I'm trying to get buildout to use a specific, forked & tweaked package from my github account, however it seems to be completely ignoring the reference and instead opting for the standard PyPi module.

Here's my buildout config:

```
[buildout]
parts = foo
find-links = http://github.com/me/themodule/tarball/version#egg=themodule-version
versions = versions
eggs = ...

[versions]
themodule=version

[foo]
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}
    themodule
```

I'm using the latest `zc.buildout` from pypi, version 1.5.2.

I've tried with both `http` and `https` for the link (because of the recent github change). The link is active and works directly, so I'm guessing it's my configuration. Am I missing something?

Comment: must specifiy the recipe for every part!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your version number is unique; if you use the same version number in your `find-links` URL as the package listed on PyPI, setuptools will happily grab the one found on PyPI instead of the one indicated by `find-links`.

We use a `{company}{counter}` pattern for private modifications, so a version `1.2.5` repackaged with our changes becomes `1.2.5acme1`. Later revisions then update the counter (`acme2`, `acme3`, etc.) until the forked-package version itself changes. It may well be necessary to set this in setup.py as well as other tools may be querying the package itself for it's version.

Comment: Thankyou, this tip solved a similar problem I had: I was trying to make buildout install pycassa from github's master branch, but since the master branch's setup.py said it was version 1.0.7, buildout would download from github, but after installation, it wouldn't find "master" as a version. 

Solution was to fork the project, set a new {company}{counter} version, push that and install from the fork.

Comment: is there no other way to achieve this? with a custom recipe perhaps?

Comment: @ErikAllik: Why do you need to achieve this in a different way? You are already forking the package.

Comment: @ErikAllik: A customized recipe *could* perhaps set `allow-hosts` temporarily, but I am not sure that'll work.

Comment: What I find annoying is that it seems not possible to just tell Buildout to download a package from a non-PyPI source, like our own repository. It is a very simple thing in `pip`, since you can just make `pip install -e git+https://github.com/jose-lpa/my_fork.git@master#egg=original_package`, but it's something that cannot be simply done in Buildout. Correct me if I'm wrong, but having to change version tags and stuff should not be necessary for this.

Comment: @JoséL.Patiño: sure it is; just provide `find-links` or `index` arguments in your `[buildout]` section. See [How to tell Buildout to install a egg from a URL (w/o pypi)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1007488)

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters. Somehow, it keeps installing it from the PyPI even when I specify the `find-links`.

Comment: @JoséL.Patiño: ah, you have a git checkout; have [`mr.developer`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) manage those instead. There is also [How do I tell buildout to ignore a binary distribution and build from source instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8852842) but for a git link the `mr.developer` route gives you a development egg and that overrides any PyPI package.

Comment: Thank you very much, Martijn :) Well, my issue I that I am using `djangorecipe`, which needs some more configuration to make it work. Basically, I followed your advice and used `mr.developer` extension to install the package, just with basic `mr.developer` configuration, nothing special. Then, in `djangorecipe`, I needed to specify the extra path for my Github checkout sources, otherwise of course Django doesn't get it! this is done in the `[django]` section by setting the place where the code is checked out in the `extra-paths` attribute. Thanks for the `mr.developer` tip! Really useful!

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, if you just want to use the forked package (and maybe re-tweak it locally at the same time you develop your main package), I'd suggest you use the amazing buildout extension  [mr.developer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer).

You can slightly modify your `buildout.cfg` to checkout your forked extension as you `./bin/buildout`. You can also specify a specific tag to checkout, if you wish to do so (double-check the user guide on PyPI for more details). Here is the skeleton for your particular setup:

```
[buildout]
parts = foo
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = *
eggs = ...

[sources]
themodule = git git@github.com:me/themodule

[foo]
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
       themodule
```