# How do I tell buildout to ignore a binary distribution and build from source instead?

Tags: buildout

I am including in a buildout an egg ([jsonlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonlib)) that uses C extensions.
On pypi a precompiled blob is present. But it's not compatible with my environment: I get a `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject` error.
I know this has to do with different environments at compile time and runtime.
To solve it buildout should compile the package instead of using the prebuilt one.

How do I tell buildout to compile a package (all packages would be fine too) no matter what precompiled egg files it finds on pypi?

Comment: Note that this question is not directly related to Plone, but I tagged it as so because many people with much buildout experience follow that tag.

Comment: What is the name of the package?

Comment: jsonlib. I am writing a buildout for a legacy project, so changing that is not an option (I'd personally use simplejson FWIW).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007488/how-to-tell-buildout-to-install-a-egg-from-a-url-w-o-pypi suggests a method that can also solve this issue, but it doesn't fell right to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have the maintainer remove the egg version; precompiled eggs only make sense on the Windows platform. Incidentially, I do not see a precompiled version on PyPI.

Comment: @silviot your suggestion would not work alone, you need to forgo using the index and overwrite it first

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
[buildout]
parts = getit

# used to show which download was fetched
download-cache = .

[getit]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
# this is the first key: ignore using the pypi index
index = .
# this is the second key: provide a direct link to the sdist
find-links = https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hachoir-core/hachoir-core-1.3.3.tar.gz
eggs = hachoir-core==1.3.3
```

And to do this only for some OS using conditional sections (disclaimer, I wrote this) with the latest version of buildout:

```
[buildout]
parts = getit
download-cache = .

[getit: macosx]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
index = .
find-links = https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hachoir-core/hachoir-core-1.3.3.tar.gz
eggs = hachoir-core==1.3.3

[getit: not macosx]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
# use pypi alright
eggs = hachoir-core==1.3.3
```

after running this, check the dist dir, it will have a copy of the fetched archive for verification: no prebuilt eggs in there ;)